# Cant edit custom post type in WordPress dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

i'm working with a WordPress site developed by someone else , when i login to dashboard and try to edit any custom post type that takes me to blank page for example there is a post type news and when i press edit button against any news item this is url

```
site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=795&action=edit
```

And there is a blank page under it , i can edit posts and pages but not custom post types , this site is done by some one else so really don't know about problem can someone help me normally why blank page comes in WordPress while editing something. if i do quick edit that is also available and change can be made through that ,

And one more thing if i want to change values of CPT from phpmyadmin (db)directly in which table should i look for custom post types

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: how do i check that if its enabled , sorry i dont know about that

Comment: See [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: so what do i check with this ? i mean if its enabled then ?

Comment: You will see error messages if the page is generating errors. Blank pages typically occur when an error halts PHP execution.

Comment: will it be avalibale in error log in public_html ?